# Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform) - When I make a request Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get data from an array in Firestore.

I'm getting an error:

```
StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)
```

when I run the following query on the firestore database:

```
Future getData() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot!.docs.forEach((doc) {
        alldata = doc["errors"];
      });
    });
  }
```

How do I properly make this query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
Future getData() async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .get();

       querySnapshot!.docs.forEach((doc) {
        alldata = (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["errors"];
      });
  }
```

Comment: Type: dynamic

Undefined name 'querySnapshot'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Answer (score -1):

Solved!

```
Future getData() async {
    final docRef =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
    docRef.get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        alldata = (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["errors"];
        print('Получен массив данных: ${alldata}');
        print('Получен массив данных: ${alldata.first}');
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The answer would be more helpful if you explain what was the issue and how your answer solves it.